# iOS Facebook Post Dialog not rendering properly on device

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am posting to a user's wall showing the standard dialog method:

```
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

It renders fine in the 5.1 Simulator but on an iPhone running 5.1 it renders the "Say something about this" text field behind the "Post to Wall" toolbar. So basically the user doesn't see it. Anyone else seeing this? Any suggestions on how to fix this? This is pretty core functionality that is not working. Pics of simulator and device provided below.

Thanks for any help.

[image: device rendering]

[image: simulator rendering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing the same thing lately, going crazy trying to figure it out.

update

Put this at the end of `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`:

```
NSString *newcontent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"50px"];
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('viewport').style.paddingTop ='%@';",newcontent]];
```

Comment: I've tried filing a bug report on this 3 times and it just sits there with the AJAX submitting indicator forever when I click "Create". I wonder how you file a bug with Facebook that their file a bug screen isn't working? Great developer support they have.

Comment: I went to implement your solution, and I got a few weird SSL errors, and then the dailog works fine...WITHOUT your fix. Is it just my imagination, or did FB just fix this on their end?

Comment: I deleted the app and tried it again without the "fix" and its still messed up. I then reimplementing the change and it looks right again. I've tried this on an original Ipad and the new Ipad, same results on both. Never saw any ssl errors though.

Comment: I don't know what is going on, but I'm not getting the issue anymore. I'll mark your answer as correct in case someone else sees this issue.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of that I did to fix this was delete the FB API files, reinstall them, and did a Clean. Other than that, I have no idea why it is working now. Which is a bit scary.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but only in the simulator, on a real phone (3.1.3) it's fine. Strange. The accepted solution fixes the problem in the simulator but on the device there is the extra padding above the blue Facebook bar...
Using the Hackbook Example Application the Dialog renders fine in the simulator and the device, which makes it even stranger.
I also tried to file a bug report but I had the same problem with the never submitting Ajax Form.

Comment: Having a bug submission form that doesn't work is a genius way to reduce your number of bugs.